# How to get the ID of a LinkButton that was previously clicked in a Repeater control?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a repeater control that has a `LinkButton` in it. Using command argument, I perform necessary functions in the code-behind. I want to turn the forecolor of a `LinkButton` to red after it is clicked and if another `LinkButton` is clicked in the `Repeater`, I want to turn off the previously clicked `LinkButton` to black and the recently clicked one to red. How do I do that? Here is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("divisionlabel") %>'
                                OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandName="MyPendingApps" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("divisionid") %>'>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_InsReqList" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton_InsReqList_Command"
                                CommandName="InspectionRequests">Inspection Requests List</asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `OnClick="LinkButtons_Click"` in every linkbutton on the form

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("divisionlabel") %>'
                                OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandName="MyPendingApps" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("divisionid") %>' OnClick="LinkButtons_Click">
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_InsReqList" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton_InsReqList_Command"
                                CommandName="InspectionRequests" OnClick="LinkButtons_Click">Inspection Requests List</asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and the code for that function is:

```
protected void LinkButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton link=(LinkButton)sender;
    if (link.ID == "yourDesiredID1")
    {
           link.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
    }
    else
    {
           link.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.YourDefaultdColor; 
    }
    if (link.ID == "yourDesiredID2")
    {
           link.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.Yellow; 
    }
    else
    {
           link.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.YourDefaultColor; 
    }
    if (link.ID == "yourDesiredID3")
    {
           link.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.Blue; 
    }
    else
    {
           link.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.YourDefaultColor; 
    }
}
```

Comment: this turns the color to red, but how can i turn off the color if another linkbutton in the same repeater is clicked?

Comment: all the linkbuttons in the repeater have the same id, except for the last one, which is not databound. so how will the if else work?

Comment: of course i tried. on debugging, i get three linkbuttons with the same id (LinkButton1). so how do i identify them based on that?i have bound the linkbuttons to a stored procedure that has many three rows depending on which the linkbuttons get repeated.

Comment: You are not getting three linkbuttons with same ID..  You are getting only one linkbutton which is clicked by you.. this code matches the desired link iD with the ID of clicked linkbutton and sets it to RED and sets other unmatched linkbuttons to "YourDesiredColor"

Comment: Under the item template of the repeater, I have just one LinkButton, which gets repeated depending on the rows returned by the stored procedure. So wont all the linkbuttons in the item template have the same ID? No matter on which linkbutton i click, the same 'if' gets executed-this is for the linkbutton in the item template, not in the footer template.Hope you understood.Is there a way to post a screen shot or something here?

Answer (score 0):

I would store a unique identifier (value, Id, ItemIndex etc) from the the ItemCommand event server side in ViewState and then in the ItemDataBound event check if unique indentifier equals that of the value in ViewState, if it does apply the class that changes the text colour to red, if not carry on binding.

Obviously there are some suttleties here that you need to think about but its a start.